# Do I need to inform UK home office before leaving UK when my EEA family relation ended?

Tags: family

I had an EEA family member residence card in UK based on unmarried partner of an EU national. We broke up few months back and immediately after our break up I decided to leave UK as I wasnt a family member anymore. 
I am about to apply for another visa to enter the UK but I didnt inform UK home office when I left UK that our relationship ended. My residence card is still valid in terms of date so does that mean Home office might ask why I didnt inform them when leaving UK ?

Comment: They might ask, but since you [seem to be applying for an EEA family permit](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/12507/2440) it shouldn't much matter.